# C++ Pass FILE * as argument to a function

Tags: c++, windows, file, arguments

I want to pass a FILE * to another function. In this function some bytes are read from the file using fread. No writing is performed.

I was wondering if I should say

```
void DoSomething(FILE *uFile)
```

or

```
void DoSomething(const FILE *uFile)
```

I was afraid to introduce a memory leak somewhere and thought that maybe const be safer. 
I was afraid that the function might create a copy of the file or so when I pass it improperly.

I create FILE * like so:

```
FILE *outfile  = fopen("c:\\myfile.dat", "wb");
```

Thank you.

Comment: is it really required to pass a file pointer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever function you pass your `FILE*` to, is eventually going to call some variant of `fread` / `fscanf` / `fwhatever`.    If you look, ALL of those functions take a (non-const) `FILE*`.

You need to be prepared to give those functions what they require.  If they're prototyped to take a non-const parameter, and you try to give them a const parameter, you'll get a compiler warning.

For this reason, I would pass in a non-const `FILE*`

Comment: I think you should actually get a warning for discarding const qualifier in C, and an error in C++.

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

C++ will never copy an *object* when you pass a *pointer* to that object as a parameter. Const  is not there to make statements about copying, it is there to make statements about modification. So you need not worry about leaks. As others have pointed out, all the functions that take `FILE*` take it non-const, so you'd only have to cast it away, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with:

`void DoSomething(const FILE *uFile)`

No duplicate of the file is created.

Comment: And what if I don't add "const"?

Comment: buy adding const you ensure that the function DoSomething() does not change any member of the FILE structure. It does not guarantee that the file content cannot be changes.

Comment: if you pass without const DoSomething() can change any member of the passed FILE structure.

Comment: and, as mentioned by abelenky, the compiler will give warnings as soon as you use any function from the standard C library, because none of them expects a const FILE * argument, simply because even when reading a file, nothing guarantees that the underlying structure is not changed, if just to keep track of buffering and filepointer position.